# Loop through list of files and download - only last file being saved

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am using the code from this post [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031095/as3-air-for-android-downloading-and-saving-remote-files) to download remote SWF files to disk.

I have an XML file that lists 3 SWF files and I am using a for each loop to go through them. Tracing out the names, shows all 3 unique file names.

When using the file download code inside the for each loop, only the last file from the list is being saved.

My exact code:

```
function onPlaylistComplete(e:Event)
{
    var List:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace("List : " + List);

    for each(var item in List.playlist_ads.ad.ad_file_path)
    {
        var urlString:String = site_url + "/" + item;
        var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
        var urlStream:URLStream = new URLStream();

        urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
        urlStream.load(urlReq);

        function loaded(event:Event):void
        {
            var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            urlStream.readBytes(fileData, 0, urlStream.bytesAvailable);
            writeBinaryFile(item, fileData);
        }


    }
}

function writeBinaryFile(name : String, array : ByteArray) : void {
    try {
        var f : File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(name);
        var fs : FileStream = new FileStream();
        fs.open(f, FileMode.WRITE);
        fs.writeBytes(array);
        fs.close();
        trace(f.nativePath + " written.");
    }
    catch (err : Error) {
        trace(err.name);
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that somehow the bytearray isn't being cleared out, or i need to use a bytearray per file?

Hope you can help.

UPDATE -  I tried the following code, taking the completion event handler out of the loop, still having the same problem and the last filename is being used. been stuck trying all manner of things for the past few hours!

```
for(i = 0; i < adArray.length; i++)
    {
        var swfItem = adArray[i];
        var urlString:String = site_url + "/" + adArray[i];
        var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
        var urlStream:URLStream = new URLStream();

        urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlStreamComplete);
        urlStream.load(urlReq);


    }
    function urlStreamComplete(event:Event):void
        {
            var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            var stream = event.target;
            stream.readBytes(fileData, 0, stream.bytesAvailable);
            try {
                var f : File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(swfItem);
                var fs : FileStream = new FileStream();
                fs.open(f, FileMode.WRITE);
                fs.writeBytes(fileData);
                fs.close();
                trace(f.nativePath + " written.");
            }
            catch (err : Error) {
                trace(err.message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all move the loaded function outside of your loop, now it is being declared multiple times. As for your issue; in your loaded function you are refering to urlStream which is being assigned within the loop. At the end of the loop it will hold the stream to the last item which in turn will be used by the loaded method. Use the event (event.target) that is passed to your loaded function to get the urlStream that dispatched the event. Same goes for item within the loaded function, you'll need some kind of dictionary setup to fetch it.

Comment: Could you possible provide some code to show what you mean? I'm not very well versed in AS3 I'm afraid!